# Get world coordinate from normalized vector and real distance

Tags: math, vector, 3d, geometry, augmented-reality

I have next scene, camera which watch on forward and object(Note: I don't know world coordinate of this object).

[image]

I need to find the world coordinate of the Object. I have next property:

- normalized direction vector
- real distance
- camera matrix4x4
  [image]

Note: vector is normalized, and this vector starts from camera not from zero.
How can I calculate world coordinate of the Object if I know only these properties. Can someone explain it.

Comment: `Object = Camera + Distance*Vector`?

Answer (score 0):

Let C be the camera position vector (The vector from the origin to the camera)

Let Ob be the object position vector.

Then the vector from the camera to the object (call it COb) is the difference between C and Ob.

Specifically COb = C - Ob. This means that Ob = C - COb => Ob = C - (RD * NDV)

Where RD = Real Distance and NDV = Normalized Direction Vector.

I'm just dashing this off so I could be off by a negative sign.